# ElasticSearch threshold for search results

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, relevance

I have an elasticsearch query that returns me the correct results in sorted order (the highest relevancy is at the top and is accurate). However, the query also returns me a lot of results and beyond the top 4 or 5, the results seem less relevant.

My question is :

> How to set a threshold such that only the most relevant results are
>   returned by the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-from-size) param in your elasticsearch query to return your configured number of results. So in your example, if you think only top 5 results are relevant for you then, you can set this `size` param to 5.

Note, As you might know already that elasticsearch results are sorted according to their score already, hence using `size` 5 means top 5 relevant documents are returned to you.

Comment: @ Amit will try today and let you know. Thanks again.